# Google Fit getHistoryClient & getSessionsClient

Tags: android, google-fit, google-fit-sdk

I found some strange behavior in Fitness request that I can't explain.
I create in parallel two requests, 
one to History like:

```
DataReadRequest readRequest = new DataReadRequest.Builder()
        .aggregate(DataType.TYPE_ACTIVITY_SEGMENT, DataType.AGGREGATE_ACTIVITY_SUMMARY)
        .bucketByTime(1, TimeUnit.HOURS)
        .enableServerQueries()
        .setTimeRange(startTime, System.currentTimeMillis(), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
        .build();

Fitness.getHistoryClient(this, GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(this))
                .readData(readRequest) ... add listeners
```

And another to Sessions like:

```
SessionReadRequest request = new SessionReadRequest.Builder()
            .setTimeInterval(startTime, System.currentTimeMillis(), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .read(DataType.TYPE_ACTIVITY_SEGMENT)
            .readSessionsFromAllApps()
            .enableServerQueries()
            .build();

    Fitness.getSessionsClient(this, GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(this))
            .readSession(request) ... add listeners
```

My `startTime` is generated like this:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(new Date());
cal.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, -1);
long startTime = cal.getTimeInMillis();
```

And I get results in my log for History:

```
DataSet{d:activity.summary:gms:aggregated[
RawDataPoint{[3, 3560719, 1]@[1552377379822000000, 1552380940541000000](4,5)}, 
RawDataPoint{[7, 38157, 1]@[1552377341665000000, 1552377379822000000](4,5)}]}
```

And for Sessions:

```
Session []
```

I see in log that I have two activity types (3 - Still (not moving) and 7 - Walking) in my fit by last hour, but how to explain that I don't get it in Sessions request?

- When I try to make `startTime` one week ago I get results in Sessions request.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a related [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53128859/steps-data-receive-from-history-api-is-not-matched-with-google-fit) wherein the data from `History API` is not matched with Fit app. And as per the documentation, `SessionsClient` provides the entry point for creating and managing `Sessions` of user activity in Google Fit. A [`Session`](https://developers.google.com/fit/android/sessions) represents a time interval with associated metadata. Sessions do not contain fitness data themselves. You can think of sessions as metadata objects with information that helps you query data from the fitness store later.